# How to remove this Microsoft Office from my Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall, microsoft-office

[image: screenshot of Apps]

I installed them hoping they would work from a random website and now I'm stuck with them.
I'm unable to do it with apt/or snap remove.

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly describe how you installed the software from that random website. A link to the instructions you followed would also be very helpful. There is no single magic incantation to safely remove any software; the correct command depends upon how the software was installed.

Comment: FWIW, that kinda looks like some sort of "Install MS Office" that's really just MS Office Online and is actually an Electron app. That may help OP narrow down where they picked it up.

Comment: Yes, these are images, these directs towards website

Answer (score 0):

I removed it via synaptic package manager, It was a package manually installed by me. Thanks Everyone for help

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I installed it via synaptic package manager and I found this way to uninstall it:

To uninstall these apps, you can execute the following command:

```
sudo dpkg --remove microsoft-online-apps
```

If this does not work, you must search for the package name by executing:

```
dpkg --list
```